# SQL - Pick first row satisfying a condition below every row satisfying another condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have this table, named `Table`

```
+----+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | A    |    0 |
|  2 | B    |    0 |
|  3 | C    |    1 |
|  4 | A    |    1 |
|  5 | D    |    0 |
|  6 | A    |    0 |
|  7 | F    |    1 |
|  8 | H    |    1 |
+----+------+------+
```

I want this result:

```
+----+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  3 | C    |    1 |
|  4 | A    |    1 |
|  7 | F    |    1 |
+----+------+------+
```

That is:

- If `Col1` = A and `Col2` = 1, take the corresponding row
- If `Col1` = A and `Col2` = 0, take the first row below it where `Col2` = 1

I tried something like

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN t.Col2 > 0
         THEN t.Col2
       WHEN t1.Col2 > 0
         THEN t1.Col2
       WHEN t2.Col2 > 0
         THEN t2.Col2
...
FROM Table t
JOIN table t1 ON t.id - 1 = t1.id
JOIN table t2 ON t.id - 2 = t2.id
...
WHERE t.Col2 = 'A'
```

but it's not quite what I was looking for.
I couldn't come up with any solution. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions SUM() and MIN():

```
with 
  cte1 as (
    select *, sum(case when col1 = 'A' and col2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) grp
    from tablename
  ),
  cte2 as (
    select *, min(case when col2 = 1 then id end) over (partition by grp order by id) next_id
    from cte1
  )
select id, col1, col2 
from cte2
where (col1 = 'A' and col2 = 1) or (id = next_id)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b88d39da1162454a81fca1349e0a23a).
Results:

```
> id | col1 | col2
> -: | :--- | ---:
>  3 | C    |    1
>  4 | A    |    1
>  7 | F    |    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
              lag(col1) over (order by id) as prev_col1,
              lag(col2) over (order by id) as pev_col2
      from t
     ) t
where col1 = 'A' and col2 = 1 or
      (pev_col1 = 'A' and prev_col2 = 0);
```

Comment: I tried it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87eebd3dc75016c8dabb139d475d1cd7) but I'm not sure I got everything working...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that finds all such rows you asked for where either it's Col1=A and Col2=1 or it's the first Col2=1 following a Col1=A and Col2=0.

A brief explanation is the query only considers rows where Col2=1. It takes the row if Col1=A of course. But it also takes the row if it looks back to find the closest previous row with Col2=1 as well as the closest previous row where Col1=A and Col2=0 and it finds former is further back than the latter (or the former doesn't exist).

```
create table MyTable (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    Col1 varchar(100) not null,
    Col2 varchar(100) not null
);

insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('A', '0');
insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('B', '0');
insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('C', '1');
insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('A', '1');
insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('D', '0');
insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('A', '0');
insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('F', '1');
insert MyTable (Col1, Col2) values ('H', '1');

select * from MyTable;

select *
    from MyTable as t
    where t.Col2 = 1
        and (t.Col1 = 'A'
            or isnull((select top (1) t2.ID
                from MyTable as t2
                where t2.ID < t.ID
                    and t2.Col2 = 1
                order by t2.ID desc
                ), 0)
                <
                (select top (1) t2.ID
                from MyTable as t2
                where t2.ID < t.ID
                    and t2.Col1 = 'A'
                    and t2.Col2 = 0
                order by t2.ID desc
                )
            )
    order by t.ID;
```